# How do I restore the deleted promo codes to discounts in Store v2?

Tags: expresso-store

So I made the upgrade to v2 and none of the v1 promo codes were migrated to the 'discounts' table. Inspecting the db, I can see them all still there in exp_store_promo_codes, but the exp_store_discounts table is empty.

Should they have all migrated? If not, how can I repopulate the discounts table? The schema is different, with different field names, so it's not a simply 1-to-1 mapping.

Comment: Anyone? Anyone? Bueller?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Expresso Store, but I assume they *should* have migrated that info as well. The first thing you can try is to revert to the old version (you made a complete DB and file backup, no?), and re-upgrade. If that isn't an option,
I would start by making a new promo, and look at the new `exp_store_discounts` table. Take an example promo from the old table, and use that data to create the new discount. From their, you can probably map out what needs to be copied over and where.

A real bungle here would probably be to forget to map **Primary Keys** together. 
Your PK from your old table needs to be the PK in the new table for there to be any chance of this working. Start by copying over one after you see how the new table is filled in, and then test migrating another row yourself, and see what you get.

If that actually works for you, depending on the number of promos, I'd write a migration script to bang the job out. Hope that helps, but one last thing... did you contact the Expresso Store people?

Also, if you look at the (what I assumed is called) `upd.express_store.php` file in the addon, you can find it's upgrade scripts. There, you can search/grep for that old and new table, and see if it was actually meant to migrate data over.

Sorry that wasn't an authoritative answer, but it should get you going, and **reach out to  DevDemon**, makers of Expresso Store

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply. I haven't checked the update script yet but it seems baffling to me that they wouldn't do that automatically! I can make a new discount code and inspect the fields to see how it maps to the  old table but writing a migration script to automate the process is a bit beyond my expertise. There are many dozens (hundreds?) of the original codes so you can see why I would be reluctant to do it by hand! I can't reach out to DevDemon because they only allow support up to 90 days from original purchase.

Comment: Oy! I wish I could help more, but I don't have access to this addon. I assume you already tried to reach out and they gave you the 90 day cold shoulder? It's worth the try...